# Input values always empty when posting using ajax from a popup window

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have a weird issue where all fields I post using ajax are empty but when I post the same code in a jsfiddle it works fine.

The only thing I can think of is that it might be because I post from a popup window (featherlight plugin).

My code:

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
  // Show extra fields when selecting option from dropdown list
  $('#offertetijden').change(function() {
     // console.log($(this).val())
     $('.hiddenoffertefields').slideDown('fast');
  });
  // Post values from new fields to php script
  $("#offertepopup").on("click",".offertebutton",function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    var $tijd = $('#offertetijden').val();
    var $volwassenen = $("input[name='volwassenen']").val();
    var $tieners = $('#tieners').val();
    var $kinderen = $('#kinderen').val();
    var $minis = $('#minis').val();
    var $babys = $('#babys').val();
    var $mailadres = $('#mailadres').val();
    url = 'includes/offertescript.php';

    var posting = $.post(url, {
      tijd: $tijd,
      volwassenen: $volwassenen,
      tieners: $tieners,
      kinderen: $kinderen,
      minis: $minis,
      babys: $babys,
      mailadres: $mailadres
    });

    posting.done(function( data ) {
     $( ".offerteresult" ).empty().slideDown('fast').append( data );
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

My HTML:

```
<div class="lightbox offertepopup" id="offertepopup">
  <span class="toolspan">Vraag een offerte aan</span>
  <form class="" action="includes/offertescript" method="post">
    <select id="offertetijden">
      <option value="none" disabled selected>Maak uw keuze</option>
      <optgroup label="Ontbijt">
        <option value="ont_1">Ma t/m Vr / 09:00 - 11:30 / 0,5 uur</option>
        <option value="ont_2">Ma t/m Vr / 09:00 - 11:30 / 1 uur</option>
        <option value="ont_3">Ma t/m Vr / 09:00 - 11:30 / 1,5 uur</option>
        <option value="ont_4">Ma t/m Vr / 09:00 - 11:30 / 2 uur</option>
        <option value="ont_5">Ma t/m Vr / 09:00 - 11:30 / 2,5 uur</option>
        <option value="ont_6">Za - Zo / 09:00 - 11:30 / 0,5 uur</option>
        <option value="ont_7">Za - Zo / 09:00 - 11:30 / 1 uur</option>
        <option value="ont_8">Za - Zo / 09:00 - 11:30 / 1,5 uur</option>
        <option value="ont_9">Za - Zo / 09:00 - 11:30 / 2 uur</option>
        <option value="ont_10">Za - Zo / 09:00 - 11:30 / 2,5 uur</option>
      </optgroup>

      <optgroup label="Lunch">
        <option value="lun_1">Ma t/m Vr / 12:00 - 15:00 / 0,5 uur</option>
        <option value="lun_2">Ma t/m Vr / 12:00 - 15:00 / 1 uur</option>
        <option value="lun_3">Ma t/m Vr / 12:00 - 15:00 / 1,5 uur</option>
        <option value="lun_4">Ma t/m Vr / 12:00 - 15:00 / 2 uur</option>
        <option value="lun_5">Ma t/m Vr / 12:00 - 15:00 / 2,5 uur</option>
        <option value="lun_6">Ma t/m Vr / 12:00 - 15:00 / 3 uur</option>
        <option value="lun_7">Za - Zo / 12:00 - 15:30 / 0,5 uur</option>
        <option value="lun_8">Za - Zo / 12:00 - 15:30 / 1 uur</option>
        <option value="lun_9">Za - Zo / 12:00 - 15:30 / 1,5 uur</option>
        <option value="lun_10">Za - Zo / 12:00 - 15:30 / 2 uur</option>
        <option value="lun_11">Za - Zo / 12:00 - 15:30 / 2,5 uur</option>
        <option value="lun_12">Za - Zo / 12:00 - 15:30 / 3 uur</option>
        <option value="lun_13">Za - Zo / 12:00 - 15:30 / 3,5 uur</option>
      </optgroup>

      <optgroup label="Diner">
        <option value="din_1">Ma t/m Do / 17:00 - 22:00 / 1 uur</option>
        <option value="din_2">Ma t/m Do / 17:00 - 22:00 / 1,5 uur</option>
        <option value="din_3">Ma t/m Do / 17:00 - 22:00 / 2 uur</option>
        <option value="din_4">Ma t/m Do / 17:00 - 22:00 / 2,5 uur</option>
        <option value="din_5">Ma t/m Do / 17:00 - 22:00 / 3 uur</option>
        <option value="din_6">Ma t/m Do / 17:00 - 22:00 / 3,5 uur</option>
        <option value="din_7">Ma t/m Do / 17:00 - 22:00 / 4+ uur</option>
        <option value="din_8">Vr t/m Zo / 17:00 - 22:00 / 1 uur</option>
        <option value="din_9">Vr t/m Zo / 17:00 - 22:00 / 1,5 uur</option>
        <option value="din_10">Vr t/m Zo / 17:00 - 22:00 / 2 uur</option>
        <option value="din_11">Vr t/m Zo / 17:00 - 22:00 / 2,5 uur</option>
        <option value="din_12">Vr t/m Zo / 17:00 - 22:00 / 3 uur</option>
        <option value="din_13">Vr t/m Zo / 17:00 - 22:00 / 3,5 uur</option>
        <option value="din_14">Vr t/m Zo / 17:00 - 22:00 / 4+ uur</option>
      </optgroup>
    </select>

    <div class="hiddenoffertefields">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <span class="toolspanbot">Hoe is u groep verdeeld?</span>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <label class="offertelabel">Aantal volwassenen:</label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="text" id="volwassenen" name="volwassenen" placeholder="Vul in">
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-6">
            <label class="offertelabel">Aantal kinderen (6-11 jaar):</label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="text" id="kinderen" name="kinderen" placeholder="Vul in">
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-6">
            <label class="offertelabel">Aantal kinderen (6-11 jaar):</label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="text" id="kinderen" name="kinderen" placeholder="Vul in">
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-6">
            <label class="offertelabel">Aantal mini's (4-7 jaar):</label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="text" id="minis" name="mini's" placeholder="Vul in">
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-6">
            <label class="offertelabel">Aantal baby's (0-4 jaar):</label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="text" id="babys" name="baby's" placeholder="Vul in">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <span class="toolspanbot">Uw gegevens</span>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <label class="offertelabel">Voornaam:</label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="text" id="mailadres" name="mailadres" placeholder="Vul in">
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-6">
            <label class="offertelabel">Achternaam:</label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="text" id="mailadres" name="mailadres" placeholder="Vul in">
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-6">
            <label class="offertelabel">Bedrijfsnaam (optioneel):</label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="text" id="mailadres" name="mailadres" placeholder="Vul in">
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-6">
            <label class="offertelabel">Telefoonnummer:</label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="text" id="mailadres" name="mailadres" placeholder="Vul in">
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-6">
            <label class="offertelabel">Opmerkingen:</label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="textarea" class="opmerkingofferte" id="mailadres" name="mailadres" placeholder="Vul in">
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="infobox">
              <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                <path fill="#2684E0" fill-rule="nonzero" d="M9.99957672 0C15.5216931 0 20 4.47746032 20 9.99957672 20 15.5216931 15.5216931 20 9.99957672 20 4.47746032 20 0 15.5216931 0 9.99957672 0 4.47746032 4.47746032 0 9.99957672 0zM9.14 8.22v7.49h1.82V8.22H9.14zM10.036 5c-.29866816 0-.54599902.10266564-.742.308S9 5.77466508 9 6.092c0 .30800154.09799902.56466564.294.77.19600098.20533436.44333184.308.742.308.2986682 0 .545999-.10266564.742-.308.196001-.20533436.294-.46199846.294-.77 0-.31733492-.097999-.57866564-.294-.784-.196001-.20533436-.4433318-.308-.742-.308z"></path>
              </svg>
              <span>
                Wanneer u met 25 of meer personen komt, kijken wij graag de beschikbaarheid voor u na. De aanvraag voor een reservering vanaf 25 personen kan verstuurd worden naar <a class="infoboxlink" href="mailto:spijkenisse@website.nu">spijkenisse@website.nu</a> of telefonisch via 0181-769000.
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button type="button" name="button" class="offertebutton">Vraag offerte aan</button>
    <div class="popupfooter">
      <a target="_blank" href="https://www.website.nl">
        <img src="assets/images/snm_dark.png" alt="">
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="offerteresult">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The fields from where I want to post are already loaded (display:none) and are shown when someone selects a value from the dropdown list. So it shouldn't be that the fields cannot by found by jQuery.

jQuery itself works, I can see the fields are posted to my script in my network tab, except the fields are all empty.

As you can see I've tried two ways of finding the value.

This

```
var $tijd = $('#offertetijden').val();
```

Or this

```
var $volwassenen = $("input[name='volwassenen']").val();
```

But both are empty.

Comment: You're calling `event.preventDefault();`, but haven't specified that `event` is the event object passed to the event handler. I don't know if this is the cause of the problem though. It should cause the script to stop with a TypeError though, I assume you've checked the console?

Comment: Yes, no errors in my console but I found out it is the popup that breaks the code. Under the answer below I posted a fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.

Apparently featherlight popup recreates the DOM inside the popup, so I had to override a config option that makes sure the HTML inside the popup always persists.

```
$.extend($.featherlight.defaults, {
  persist: true
});
```

This fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me the values aren't ready when you do the posting.

How about wrapping the block with `setTimeout()`? Like this,

```
setTimeout(function(){
   var posting = $.post(url, {
      tijd: $tijd,
      volwassenen: $volwassenen,
      tieners: $tieners,
      kinderen: $kinderen,
      minis: $minis,
      babys: $babys,
      mailadres: $mailadres
  });

  posting.done(function( data ) {
     $( ".offerteresult" ).empty().slideDown('fast').append( data );
  });
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This doesn't work either. I have no idea why jQuery can't find the values.

Comment: Do you have a fiddle?

Comment: Yes here: https://jsfiddle.net/p51nvqmk/ when you click on `OFFERTE` the popup shows but the alert only shows (null), but without the popup, so not clicking on `OFFERTE` and immediatly selecting from the dropdown the alert shows the correct selection.

Comment: When I click the `OFFERTE` , I can the see the alert with value. I am a bit confused.

Comment: Can you refresh the page? If you only click OFFERTE first (so not the dropdown) then a popup shows up, there you select a value and press the button inside the popup. This shows (null) for me.